# Mahout - vectors to cluster

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

I run K-Means using:

```
KMeansDriver.run(new Path("./bd.seq.file"), new Path(clustersLoc), new Path("output"),
            new EuclideanDistanceMeasure(), 0.001, 10, true, 0.5, false);
```

My aim is to know what cluster each of my original vectors belong to.
From what I understand, this is supposed to be in output/clusteredPoints/part-m-00000, however this file looks like an empty (120 bytes) sequence file.

What gives?

Comment: Another clue I just found out. This happens only on Mahout 0.7. So, this is either a bug, or an undocumented change in behavior. In Mahout 0.5 I got a file under the path output/clusteredPoints
/part-m-00000 containing the mapping of vector to cluster ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I finally got it (at least partially). It has to do with `KMeansDriver.run()` 8th parameter. 
If it has a value of '0' it behaves the same as in Mahout 0.5.
The parameter's name is 'clusterClassificationThreshold' and its javadoc states:

> Is a clustering strictness / outlier removal parrameter. Its value
>   should be between 0 and 1. Vectors having pdf below this value will
>   not be clustered.

For any Mahout beginners like me, pdf is acronym for "Probability density function".
I'm not sure I really got what this parameter is (googling did not help here, the javadocs are ALL you're gonna get), but I guess that because it is part of a mechanism that filters the original vectors Mahout developers chose to disable the clustering points in case that it is not '0'.